# Issue where Wifi works for skype but not for any browser?

Tags: windows-vista, browser, wireless-networking, skype

On a Windows Vista machine when connecting to broadband using wifi I see the connection OK, and things like Skype work fine wirelessly, but all browsers give page not found errors. Have tried IE, Firefox & Chrome.

I suspect its something to do with my Norton Antivirus but Skype is working fine.

Also the cabled connection to broadband works fine for all web connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the browser always give an error or only most of the time?

Comment: While you are wireless, run "cmd" and type "ping www.google.com" (without the quotes). Does it say "request timed out" or "reply from [some number]"?

Comment: @Ludwig the error is all of the time when wireless. @AdamB I'll give that a try, its my brothers laptop and he's in Ireland asleep now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a firewall issue.
Skype is known to work through partly firewalled paths.

While `Skype` is working, can you do a **`ping`** to say, `www.google.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a DNS issue.
Does http://74.125.67.100 take you to google?

Comment: Would this make a difference on the same machine between wireless & wired connection to the broadband router?

Comment: There should be no difference in internet access from a Wireless connection to a Wired connection, in regards to your DNS.

Comment: Thats what I thought. It works fine when connected by wire to the router, its only when wireless that the browers don't connect but skype still does.

Comment: So probably not a DNS issue.

Comment: Why can't it be? If your router or AP gives a different DNS server depending on wired or wireless, that could happen. It could also be an issue with binding to that adapter, but I have no idea how to check that or fix it. Just mentioning it to see if that can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your router for the [MTU value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit). Set it to a value of round about 1400 and see if that resolves your problem. Some ISP's routers drop packets if they're too big rather than fragmenting them.